# Should it be be ἐν or ἐστιν in Galatians 5:22 & Ephesians 5:9?

Tags: greek, grammar, galatians, ephesians

The Apostle Paul uses the verb ἐστιν when expressing the "Fruit of the Spirit" in Galatians

> 22 But the fruit of the Spirit ***is*** love, joy, peace, longsuffering, gentleness, goodness, faith,

Westcott and Hort 1881

> ὁ δὲ καρπὸς τοῦ πνεύματός ***ἐστιν*** ἀγάπη, χαρά, εἰρήνη, μακροθυμία, χρηστότης, ἀγαθωσύνη, πίστις,.

But in Ephesians he uses the preposition ἐν in relation to the same "Fruit of the Spirit"

Ephesians 5:9 (KJV)

> 9 (For the fruit of the Spirit is in all goodness and righteousness and truth;)

Westcott and Hort 1881

> ὁ γὰρ καρπὸς τοῦ φωτὸς ***ἐν*** πάσῃ ἀγαθωσύνῃ καὶ δικαιοσύνῃ καὶ ἀληθείᾳ,.

So how can these two verses be understood from a grammatical point of view?

Comment: An interesting question which might require the dedicated abilities of a genuine Textual Critic to properly comment upon, I would suggest.

Comment: In the second instance, Ephesians 5:9, simply a verb ἐστί is missing but implied, so in English rightly translated as: "the Spirit *is* in...". There are ample instances, when the verb "is" is missing but implied. For example, in Luke 16:16 Ὁ νόμος καὶ οἱ προφῆται μέχρι Ἰωάνου - That is to say: "Law and prophets [have been] before John". Or in ancient gnomic utterance μηδὲν ἄγαν! - "Nothing in excess" the verb "to be" is implied "Let nothing be in excess!" μηδὲν [εἴη] ἄγαν.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would read both the Greek and English as implying that *all goodness and righteousness and truth* (πᾶς ἀγαθωσύνη καὶ δικαιοσύνη καὶ ἀλήθεια) are foundational for the virtues listed in Galatians.

That is:  the fruits of the Spirit are (in fact) love, joy, peace, longsuffering, gentleness, goodness, and faith; but all of these arise out  of, or "lie in",  the goodness, righteousness and truth that are qualities of the Spirit.

Comment: "Fruit" is singular, not plural.